# Metadata(PalletNotFound) with subxt

Tags: subxt, metadata

I am using [subxt](https://github.com/paritytech/subxt/tree/master) to get the list of parachains on the Polkadot network. Firstly I used the `subxt-cli` tool to download the metadata:

```
subxt metadata --url https://rpc.polkadot.io:443 -f bytes > polkadot-metadata.scale
```

The file looks fine:

```rs
#[subxt::subxt(runtime_metadata_path = "metadata/polkadot_metadata.scale")]
pub mod polkadot {}
```

And then I query the storage to retrieve the parachains:

```rs
let storage_query = polkadot::storage().paras().parachains();

let result = api
        .storage()
        .at_latest()
        .await?
        .fetch(&storage_query)
        .await?;
```

But when I run it I get an error:

```
Error: Metadata(PalletNotFound)
```

What am I doing wrong here? How can I check that I have the correct metadata? Or the list of pallets I can query?

The query on PolkadotJS is the following:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, thanks for asking about this topic

Any metadata on the disk can be further inspected with the use of subxt-cli, we've also added some new features that allows users to quickly explore the metadata information (in [this PR](https://github.com/paritytech/subxt/pull/950)). However, you can still go back and forth between the binary format and the JSON format with older subxt versions.

As you mentioned above, the metadata is downloaded as

```bash
cargo run --release -p subxt-cli -- metadata --url https://rpc.polkadot.io:443 -f bytes > artifacts/test_metadata.scale
```

We can see all the pallets present in the metadata by doing a

```bash
cargo run --release -p subxt-cli -- explore --file artifacts/test_metadata.scale

..
    ParachainsOrigin
    Paras
    ParasDisputes
..
```

Then we can see the storage entries of the `Paras` pallet with the following

```bash
cargo run --release -p subxt-cli -- explore --file artifacts/test_metadata.scale Paras storage

..
    ParaLifecycles
    Parachains
    PastCodeHash
..
```

Using the same code lines from your question I do get the output:

```bash
cargo run --example stack_8663                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     14:02:55

polkadot::storage().paras().parachains(): Some([Id(1000), Id(1001), Id(1002), Id(2000), Id(2002), Id(2004), Id(2006), Id(2007), Id(2008), Id(2011), Id(2012), Id(2013), Id(2019), Id(2021), Id(2026), Id(2027), Id(2030), Id(2031), Id(2032), Id(2034), Id(2035), Id(2037), Id(2039), Id(2040), Id(2043), Id(2046), Id(2048), Id(2051), Id(2052), Id(2053), Id(2055), Id(2056), Id(2058), Id(2086), Id(2090), Id(2091), Id(2092), Id(2093), Id(2094), Id(2097), Id(2101), Id(2104), Id(2106), Id(3333), Id(3334), Id(3336)])
```

You can give my example a go from the branch [lexnv/stack_8663](https://github.com/paritytech/subxt/tree/lexnv/stack_8663) (commit [6c4c58e0](https://github.com/paritytech/subxt/commit/6c4c58e00491fe23f13ea9b7753af9862438f966)):

```rust
    // Create a new API client, configured to talk to Polkadot nodes.
    let api = OnlineClient::<PolkadotConfig>::from_url("wss://rpc.polkadot.io:443").await?;

    // Build the query.
    let storage_query = polkadot::storage().paras().parachains();

    // Fetch the result.
    let result = api
        .storage()
        .at_latest()
        .await?
        .fetch(&storage_query)
        .await?;

    println!("polkadot::storage().paras().parachains(): {result:?}");
```

#### Further Debugging

The `Error: Metadata(PalletNotFound)` suggests that the pallet `Paras` (in this case I presume) is missing.
There are two possibilities here:

- Is your metadata in sync? (ie, you may be using older metadata -- please check that the path is correct and regenerate the metadata as above)
- Are you doing any other subxt calls? (ie, you may call other queries for storage / tx with other pallets, pallets that may no longer be present in the chain)

Another thing worth mentioning is how you build your subxt client (although not that relevant -- I construct the client with `OnlineClient::<PolkadotConfig>::from_url("wss://rpc.polkadot.io:443").await?`).

Comment: Brilliant answer thanks! Constructing the client with: let api = OnlineClient::<PolkadotConfig>::from_url("wss://rpc.polkadot.io:443").await?; works!!